# Status:CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED

Tags: domain-registration

i am having a domain registered with godaddy when i am looking through my domain details i found this in the who is lookup , what is this means and if i would like to transfer my domain to another registrar will it be hassle free ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED` is an [Extensible Provisioning Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Provisioning_Protocol) code (typically used with a subset of [gTLD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain)) which is functionally equivalent to the `REGISTRAR-LOCK` status described at the [Registrar-Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registrar-Lock) Wikipedia entry:

> REGISTRAR-LOCK is a status code that
>   can be set on an Internet domain name
>   by the sponsoring registrar of the
>   domain name.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) This is usually
>   done in order to prevent unauthorized,
>   unwanted or accidental changes to the
>   domain name.
>
> When set, the following actions are
>   prohibited by the domain name
>   registry:
>
> ```
> * Modification of the domain name, including:
>       o Transferring of the domain name
>       o Deletion of the domain name
> ```
>
> Renewal of the domain name is,
>   however, still possible when
>   REGISTRAR-LOCK is set.

GoDaddy provides facilities for [locking and unlocking](http://help.godaddy.com/article/410) your domain if you plan to transfer it to a different registrar or make changes to the registrant information; it is generally recommended that you keep your domain locked when you are not making changes or transferring, as unlocked domains are vulnerable to unauthorized transfers.

Comment: A note on that last paragraph: If you're planning to transfer the domain do not edit the registrant information beforehand unless absolutely necessary. It'll prohibit transfers for two months. (The panel will not warn you about this.) It obviously can't be avoided if the information is unusable, but resist the temptation to "just" correct a minor typo or switch to a preferred e-mail address if the current one still works okay. Do it after the transfer.

Comment: so if i assume correct if want to transfer my domain from godaddy, just make the transfer request  to my new registrar and rest will be taken care if i dont touch anything on godaddy?

Comment: @sansknwoledge - No, you have to unlock the domain at your registrar to transfer it. The [domain name transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar#Domain_name_transfer) process documented at Wikipedia describes what you will need to do.